# Switch between Python 3.x and 3.y through anaconda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I have a HDP cluster and I'm working with couple data scientist, we're working on  Python 3.5 (anaconda3) and I would switch to the new Python version 3.6 while keeping the previous version which is 3.5

My questions:

Is that possible having 2 version of Python like 3.5 and 3.6 through anaconda?

if that true, how can I switch between those two version?

Answer (score 4):

You have to create two environments:

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5
conda create -n py36 python=3.6
```

then you can change to the desired environment using

```
source activate py35
```

or
    source activate py36

you can then `pip instal` and use `python` specific to that environment

To leave an environment use

```
source deactivate
```

read up on it [in the anaconda documentation](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)

**Note:** on windows, use an anaconda prompt and leave out the `source`

Comment: Note that `py35` and `py36` are just example names for the two environments - you can call them whatever you like. Also while you can use `pip` to install packages in a conda env, wherever possible you should use `conda install` instead as then conda will keep track of the dependencies versus other packages in the env, will be able to update the package later, etc. To check if a package is available to install with conda, use `conda search`.

Comment: Also note that in `conda>=4.4`, the command is `conda activate`, not `source activate` (the latter is also only valid on Linux and macOS)