# have 3.x and 3.y anaconda version on offline mode

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49529465/switch-between-python-3-x-and-3-y-through-anaconda) few days ago about switching between 2 versions of Anaconda.

what I'm looking for now is to understand why I got an erreur where I tried to create python 3.5 environment on off line mode:

```
#conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda --offline Fetching package 
metadata ... Solving package specifications: . PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: '' Package missing in current linux-64 channels:
  - python 3.5*

You can search for packages on anaconda.org with

    anaconda search -t conda python
```

should I install an additional version of Anaconda which contents python 3.5 or the present version Anaconda has all subversion of python 3 (i.e 3.6 3.5 3.4 ....) ?

Answer (score 1):

No, Python 3.5 is a package like numpy, pandas, etc. You need to download the package an install it. You should not install a separate version of Anaconda to get a new version of Python.

You can create an empty environment by leaving off any package specifications, then install whatever you want into the environment.

```
conda create -n py35 --offline
conda install --offline -n py35 python-3.5.tar.bz2
```

Comment: Where should I find the `python-3.5.tar.bz2` ?

Comment: I can't found this package at all.. en the other hand I found this issue https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/4267, the conda 4.2.9 has a bug on offline mode

Comment: That link says the bug was fixed in `conda` 4.3 in May 2017. What version do you have?