# Create 3 environments of Python 3 in Anaconda on offline mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

In this [guide](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html) of Conda, they explain how to setup different version of Python within Anaconda by creating different environment. so I proceed to create 3 environments: Python 3.4 Python 3.5 and Python 3.6.
I setup the last version of Conda [4.4.10 (2018-02-09)](http://4.4.10%20(2018-02-09))

## What I've done:

#### python 3.6

```
$conda create -n py36 python=3.6 anaconda --offline

Solving environment: done

Package Plan

  environment location: /opt/Anaconda/Anaconda3-5.1.0/envs/py36

  added / updated specs:
    - anaconda
    - python=3.6


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    alabaster:                          0.7.10-py36h306e16b_0
    anaconda:                           5.1.0-py36_2
    .................OTHERs PKGS.......................

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
#
# To activate this environment, use:
# > source activate py36
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use:
# > source deactivate
```

here we can see that I succefually create a py36 environment:

```
$conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /opt/Anaconda/Anaconda3-5.1.0
py36                     /opt/Anaconda/Anaconda3-5.1.0/envs/py36
```

#### Python 3.5:

```
$conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda --offline

Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python=3.5

Current channels:

  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
```

When I checked out the Python version I have, I get:

```
$conda search python --offline
Loading channels: done
Name                       Version                   Build  Channel
python                     3.3.0                         3  defaults
python                     3.3.0                         4  defaults
python                     3.3.0                      pro0  defaults
python                     3.3.0                      pro1  defaults
python                     3.3.1                         0  defaults
python                     3.3.2                         0  defaults
python                     3.3.2                         1  defaults
.....................ALL Versions between...................
python                     3.6.3                h6c0c0dc_5  defaults
python                     3.6.3                hc9025b9_1  defaults
python                     3.6.3                hcad60d5_0  defaults
python                     3.6.3                hefd0734_2  defaults
python                     3.6.4                hc3d631a_0  defaults
python                     3.6.4                hc3d631a_1  defaults
```

#### Python 3.4: Same thing than 3.5

Comment: You should probably first install python 3.5 with conda, and then do an offline install

Comment: @Adonis Could you explain more, do you mean online mode?

Comment: [This post is related], you just have to transpose it with Python, like here: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python/files?version=3.5.1

Comment: What did you mean by "transpose it with Python", what shoud I transpose and how ?

Comment: My bad, didn't include the link to the post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41577527/4121573. What you do is untar the Python package downloaded from their website, and then it should be available for offline use, as far as I see, you don't have Python 3.4/3.5 locally available for conda

Comment: did you see the output of `$conda search python --offline` above? aren't those packages avalaible in local machine??

Comment: @hisi What is your question here? Isn't this the same as the post I answered yesterday? Why isn't it a duplicate? Those packages are definitely not all available on your local machine, otherwise it would probably take up several TB of hard drive space. I'm not sure why the `--offline` flag isn't doing anything for the search though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [have 3.x and 3.y anaconda version on offline mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49777621/have-3-x-and-3-y-anaconda-version-on-offline-mode)

Comment: @darthbith I've still a problem with Conda env, in my yesterday question it was a bug which created the problem:  github.com/conda/conda/issues/4267. so I installed the last version and asked new question. and if you notice the output message of the two question isn't the same

Comment: No, I am talking about the question that @Adonis linked to. How is this different that your 3.x and 3.y question?

Comment: @darthbith I downloaded the Python 3.5 and 3.4 packages and I've imported those packages on `/opt/Anaconda/Anaconda3-5.1.0/pkgs/`, however the problem have not still resolved....Maybe I was  hurried to ask the question. I will check what I've done so far and I will update my question

Comment: But if you do what I said in my answer to the other question once you download the tarballs (and in my answer to your other other question about how to install packages offline) doesn't that fix it? I still don't understand how this question is different than the 3.x and 3.y one

Comment: @darthbith 3 raison why 1) this version is newer that last question. 2) the main problem in last question is the bug however in this question is samethig else which I always ignore it. 3) I copied the python3.5 package in conda/pkgs and still have the problem. I will bring back the updates. Thanks